# Integration on manifolds and improper integration

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, smooth-manifolds

Consider the usual concept of integral on a smooth manifold (the one built using partitions of unity). When applied to the usual smooth structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$, does it coincide with the concept of improper integral? I assume so, but I am not sure.

A concrete example: is the function $\mathbb{e} ^{\mathbb{i} \|x\|^2}$ integrable (in the sense of integration on manifolds, not in the sense of improper integrals) on $\mathbb{R^n}$? (I know that it isn't Riemann or Lebesgue integrable.)

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it is integrable? What sense does it make? Usually, when integrating forms on manifolds, one considers differential forms with compact support. Then, given a form with noncompact support, one can integrate it in special cases, similarly to how it is done in Euclidean space.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yubal says, the thing works as in the usual case: some improper integrals can be computed, some not. The clearest example is the volume, which can be computed for any manifold, by integrating the volume form $\varOmega$, which of course has not compact support unless the manifold $M$ is compact. There you pick one exhaustion of $M$ by compact sets $K_n\subset$Int$(K_{n+1})$ and bump functions $\varphi_n$ which are $\equiv 1$ on $K_n$ and $\equiv 0$ off $K_{n+1}$. Then you have integrals with compact support
$I_n=\int_M \varphi_n\varOmega$ and show that $I=\lim_n I_n$ exists (including it is $+\infty$). Also that the limit doesn't depend on the compacts sets nor the bump functions chosen. By definition, $I=\int_M\varOmega$.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Consider the last words of your answer: "by definition, $I=\int_M \Omega". Not true, I say. The integral of any form is defined with the aid of a partition of unity subordinated to some atlas, and this is not what you do. Essentially, what I ask is whether the standard construction (with partitions of unity) is equivalent to the construction with compact exhaustions (on Riemannian manifolds one may also consider exhaustions with balls of some fixed centerpoint).

Comment: What I mean "by definition" is that if you have a definition for forms compactly supported, you can use exhaustions to extend that definition to not compactly supported forms. The example of volume is the most elementary one of this. For a form compactly supported exhaustions make no difference, because some compact of any given exhaustion must contain the support of the form. On the other hand, partitions of unity is just the tool to reduce the definition of integral on manifolds to integral on euclidean spaces, no matter which definition you consider.